# How to configure ubuntu 14.04 to run Icewm as default desktop display Manager

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, display-manager, icewm

How to configure ubuntu 14.04 to run Icewm as default desktop display Manager.
which files to Configure to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using LightDM as "login manager"? You can edit the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf to contain:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=icewm-session
```

or

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=IceWM
```

An explanation of the differences between icewm-session and IceWM can be found in the [IceWM FAQ](http://www.icewm.org/FAQ/IceWM-FAQ-3.html):

"Beginning with IceWM 1.2.13 there is a binary icewm-session. This binary helps you to handle all IceWM subparts (icewmbg, icewm, icewmtray, startup, shutdown started in this order). Therefore you can use icewm-session to start IceWM. icewm now starts only window manager itself."

Comment: Thank you for your replay but its not working on reboot of the terminal. Normal Desktop loads

Comment: Sorry I got the configuration files mixed up. I have now updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you Provide detail steps how to configure after installing icewm.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to configure IceWM? If so then I suggest the Ubuntu documentation on IceWM @ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IceWM.

Comment: I have confiure Icewm and automatic login.  It runs on manual input startx command. How to run this startx command when system boots up during after  automatic login.Changing rc.local does not effects

Comment: I'm sorry, I find it hard to understand your question. If you have configured automatic login then there's no need to make any configurations to be read upon executing startx since you're automatically logged in to the desktop environment, right? Please clarify or post a new question.

Comment: OK thanks for your support I have done for the day.